# Getting app-scoped ID with facebook login: the ID I receive is'nt unique

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I use Facebook Login on my website, and I want to upgrade it to the last version, with the app-scoped user id. Normally, the ID I should receive from Facebook should be unique.

However, when I test with a new fb account, the id I receive (e.g. ***123***) is the same as the one on the user public profile URL: **https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=123**

This is not really safe... Anyone could copy the ID of someone else profile URL and login with his ID

How do I force asking the new app-scoped id?

Right now nobody had signed up to my website

P.S. Sorry if my english isn't that good

Comment: It's funny the way StackOverflow delete automatically my "Hi everyone"

Comment: Salutations don't really help with understanding the problem at hand and are therefore considered "noise". [The system automatically removes these types of things at the beginning of posts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: I dunno how my mum would feels if I would have said that when she was teaching good manners to me

Answer (score 0):

> This is not really safe... Anyone could copy the ID of someone else profile URL and login with his ID

Not possible, Facebook Login wise. If your site is designed to login people just based on ID alone that's not good at all. That's a security weakpoint in your site, not Facebook.

If your application at any point in time used v1.0 then some of the IDs returned will be Global IDs. There is no risk that you should be worried about here.

Comment: My app used v2.0, but I'm still getting global ids for new users. Before I used global id & username to login, but Facebook doesnt provide username for new facebook accounts. I guess I have to login these users with the app-scoped id only then...